# How to display multiple pages under tabs similar to a Browser tab retaining loaded pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have an application where we have a single level navigation menu with some heavy-duty pages on each link. The user can switch back and forth between these pages frequently to obtain information that he needs.

Once the page gets generated, it wouldn't change for the session. However, the page is specific to the user, hence we cant cache it.

I was trying to come up with a solution where we generate the page once, and keep it hidden in the background until its link is clicked, but haven't been able to get my head around this.

One of the ways I thought was to have multiple `div` tags (one for each page) on one page and keep toggling the `visibility` as the links are pressed, but that would end up making this single page very heavy. Someone also suggested using `iFrames`, but I am not really comfortable using the `iFrames` much and I'm not even sure, if it would be any helpful either.

Can you guys please suggest a few approaches to tackle the issue?

**update:** Just to clarify, we are fine with keeping the pages separate and navigate across using a standard menu bar. We were just looking for ways to optimize the performance as we know that the pages once generated wouldn't change and there should be some way to tap that benefit.

Comment: If the pages are really that big, you dont want to put them in DIVs and hide them.  It will cause your DOM to be too big and your page will slow way down.

Comment: you can use `div` tags idea with `Ajax` call for each `div` to decrease the response time of the whole page

Comment: It sounds to me like you have some major UI design problems.  I would consult a specialty firm to redesign the UI layer.  If you really have that much on one page, the page is not context specific.  Just sounds like all around bad practice.

Comment: @Miroprocessor when they start out they will have a basic page... but once they start loading those DIVs up the browser will start to bog down.  Selectors will suffer, and the page will eventually become unusable.

Comment: hmm.. just as I had thought.. So, in essence you guys suggest that it would be better to keep the pages separate.. ?

Comment: Well, like any problem in Software Engineering its really hard to say unless we can see everything.  That said, I am never a fan of big views, and if you are saying you want to make that view bigger, then yes I would say keep them separate.  Sounds to me like each of those pages needs to be broken down MORE.  Time to normalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic3) which specifically tackles the issue of how to user-level cache. Also, it might be more manageable to break each tab into a user control. That way your ASP.NET page has just the tab control and 1 user control for each section under the tab. It makes managing tabs much easier.

EDIT:

What I would do in your case, since you say the data won't change for the user, is I would grab the static data from the database and then I would store that data in the Session cache. THe session cache is specific per user and you can try to retrieve the static data from there instead of repetitively calling the database.

Comment: but each time the tabs are switched, the user-control would have to be re-generated.. isnt it..?

Comment: @Danish - Yes but just the user control. Not the whole entire page. The rest of the page can be cached

Comment: As I said, each of the page has information which is user specific. There is hardly any generic content there. So, even fragments (user controls, in this case) cant be cached.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that if you did some server side caching it would help if your problem is processing of these huge views.  You can cache views per user you know.  Just set the expiration to something reasonable so the memory does not get out of hand.

Comment: Read the article I linked Danish. It tells you exactly how to cache user controls on a per user basis.

Comment: @icemanind: While I agree that server side caching using user as a factor is probably the best approach that link doesn't seem to talk about how to cache stuff per user. In fact, the section you link to seems to talk about how some stuff on a page might be user specific whereas other stuff isn't and then talks about how to cache those other things as user controls. Can you point me more specifically to how you would do caching by user. I'm kind of intrigued now and can't really think where to go with it... :)

Comment: @Chris - Sure. One of the best articles overall on caching would be [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx). Another article you can reference is [this one](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022802-1.aspx). It is hard to find an article specifically on the topic. You almost just have to read them all, then just it together on your own

Comment: Guys, caching does sound like the best bet as of now, but considering that there can be upto 500 concurrent users and there would be a farm to balance the load, I'm just afraid that we might end up complicating things for a little or no gain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax tab control for this purpose

Comment: And how does that do anything other than load the page in another div?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ASP Multiview control. Just remember that even though the different views are hidden when not active, their viewstate is still being sent back and forth. Can be a benefit if you need to check control values across views though.